# Initially hidden iframe won't load properly until it's refreshed. How can I fix?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, iframe, anythingslider

I've been having crazy hell with getting (jquery plugin) AnythingSlider to load properly in an initially hidden iframe without manually refreshing said iframe.

The plugin seems to load as if the iframe were at the top of the page, and consequently most of the content is out of frame.

I've got a modified script (Slicker Show & Hide) that vanishes the iframe before the page loads, and I think this may be causing the problem (in that the AnythingSlider plugin can't retrieve the dimensions of it's frame), but I can't seem to find a way around it - something like making it appear offscreen, and then when called hide, move onscreen and show?

The site is live [here](http://portiaab.com/rainbowwhitebg1024.html)

If anyone could please give me a hand, I'd love to get this set up so I can move on!

Thanks

edit: or, if that's not possible, how can I force the frame to refresh the first time I 'show' it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#iframe').css("display", "block").attr("src", "gallery.php");
```

Comment: Thanks David. Sorry to appear an complete novice, but what is the gallery.php reference? I don't believe I'm using any PHP.

Comment: That is the URL of the iframe, src="blah.html" -- This will display the hidden iframe, and then refresh it with the URL provided. The downside to this, is that it is loaded after it is made visible, possibly resulting in a delay while it loads. You may be able to just move it off the screen like you had originally suggested, maybe with absolute positioning in the negatives.

Comment: Ah, I get you. I've inserted that code now, and it still does the same thing unfortunately. Have I done anything wrong please? http://portiaab.com/rainbowwhitebg1024.html